# Error response from daemon: bridge is a pre-defined network and cannot be removed

Tags: docker

CentOS 7

Docker 20.10

I want to delete all networks.

```
docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

As you can see no containers. I was removed it before.
I try this:

```
docker network ls
NETWORK ID     NAME      DRIVER    SCOPE
1b6758d38df3   bridge    bridge    local
89dea066d590   host      host      local
8e235018309e   none      null      local
```

And this:

```
docker network rm 1b6758d38df3
Error response from daemon: bridge is a pre-defined network and cannot be removed
```

P.S the folder `/var/lib/docker` is empty

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are the *system networks* included in every **Docker** installation, they are not like *user-defined networks* and cannot be removed.

From the docs for the[`docker network prune` command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_prune/):

> Note that system networks such as bridge, host, and none will never be pruned

From the [Network containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/networkingcontainers/) tutorial page:

> Every installation of the Docker Engine automatically includes three default networks.
> [...]
> The network named bridge is a special network. Unless you tell it otherwise, Docker always launches your containers in this network.

This would mean that removing those networks would break some of **Docker**'s networking features.

Answer (score 0):

For what purpose do you want to remove/delete default network provided by Docker... Please share your use case so some one from community can guide you accordingly...

Bridge, Host & None are default & pre defined network... These networks are created during installation of docker....

> Bridge - All containers without **--network** options get created within
> bridge network only
> To verify this you can run following commands -

```
docker run -it --rm --name=default-bridge-container1 busybox
```

As above command does not have --network option then it will be create container **default-bridge-container1** under bridge network. To verify this, Run

```
docker network inspect bridge
```

Under containers section of inspect command, you will see container name **default-bridge-container1** with IP assigned to it from bridge subnet.

> Host - this option tells to use underlying host network
>
> None - Container with --network=none means container is running in
> isolation & it has no access to inward or outward network.

Comment: After uninstall Docker the  default network  also was removed